# Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts within Settings

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

The left button of my trackpad no longer works, and I had previously deactivated the touchpad, which I want to reactvate.
So I managed to open Settings, which opened in users configuation.
My question is: how do I switch to move to the mouse configuation in the left panel ? I could not figure out how to give focus on the left panel.
I use Ubuntu 22.04 with gnome desktop with Wayland.
Thanks very much for your support.

Comment: It will be nice if you remove the formatting in bold and big letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyboard support in some graphical Linux applications, including Gnome system tools, sometimes remains extremely flaky, even up in 2022.

- If the left pane is focussed, arrow keys will move between panes. The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key will move the focus to the right pane, but while tabbing cycles through too many things, it never returns focus on the left pane. Also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will not work.
- There is a shortcut, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, that should, according to the Keyboard shortcuts pane (the help screen that appears when you select "Keyboard shortcuts", of press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> and that you cannot leave open to try it in the application), bring you to the "previous pane", but that does not help to bring you to a pane you did not yet visit.

⟶ One trick to activate the left pane with the keyboard is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to focus the search, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

⟶ Alas, beware when you arrive in the subpane "Applications". There is no way to move to different applications with the keyboard. Typing also will not help. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> can get you back. It works better though in the subpane "Privacy".

Comment: Hello vanadium, thanks for your detailed explanations. I mannaged to reactivate my touchpad. Second step will be to solve the issue about left trackpad button not working, but that is another story :-) Thanks again!